# Approach to run network tests

Tags: c++, testing, network-programming, automated-tests

I've got a C++ project on Linux which implements a network application. I run my tests manually by CLI on different computers, the tests connect to each other and send data. When the tests are completed, they print some stats.

I would like to automate my tests, I need a script or a framework that can run my test remotely on different computers, can control it, and can collect test output.

Is there a testing framework which can do what I need, or should I implement it via Perl or Shell or...?

Comment: @BЈовић OP doesn't say that it's unit tests anywhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no answer to this question, I use bash script to run my test remotely via ssh for now. It looks similar to

```
remote_wait()
{
  host=$1
  shift
  ssh $host "for pid in \"$@\"; do while kill -0 \$pid; do sleep 1; done; done"
}

run_remote()
{
  host=$1
  shift
  app=$1
  shift
  scp $app $host:/tmp/test_receiver 1>&2 || exit 1
  ssh ${host} "{ $remote_app $@ >$app_log 2>&1 & }; echo \$! "
}

echo Starting receiver...
receiver_pid=`run_remote $userhost $1`

echo Starting sender...
./sender &
sender_pid=$!

wait $sender_pid
remote_wait $userhost $receiver_pid
```